# VBS Invalid Character

Tags: iis-6, windows-xp, vbscript

This is a simple VBS script.  But when I double-click on this, I get Invalid Character 800A0408 on Line 1, Character 1, which I think is the first "Dim".  I am new to VBS--can u tell me what I did wrong?  FYI, I have an XP OS and IIS6 Manager installed.

```
' This script adds the necessary Windows Presentation Foundation MIME types 
' to an IIS Server.
' To use this script, just double-click or execute it from a command line.
' Running this script multiple times results in multiple entries in the IIS MimeMap.

Dim MimeMapObj
Dim MimeMapArray
Dim WshShell
Dim oExec
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2

' Set the MIME types to be added
Dim MimeTypesToAddArray = Array(".manifest", "application/manifest", ".xaml", _
    "application/xaml+xml", ".application", "application/x-ms-application", _
    ".deploy", "application/octet-stream", ".xbap", "application/x-ms-xbap", _
    ".xps", "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument")

' Get the mimemap object 
Set MimeMapObj = GetObject("IIS://LocalHost/MimeMap")

' Call AddMimeType for every pair of extension/MIME type
For counter = 0 to UBound(MimeTypesToAddArray) Step 2
    AddMimeType MimeTypesToAddArray(counter), MimeTypesToAddArray(counter+1)
Next

' Create a Shell object
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Stop and Start the IIS Service
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("net stop w3svc")
Do While oExec.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("net start w3svc")
Do While oExec.Status = 0
    WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Set oExec = Nothing

' Report status to user
WScript.Echo "Windows Presentation Foundation MIME types have been registered."

' AddMimeType Sub
Sub AddMimeType(ByVal Ext, ByVal MType)

    ' Get the mappings from the MimeMap property. 
    MimeMapArray = MimeMapObj.GetEx("MimeMap")

    ' Add a new mapping. 
    i = UBound(MimeMapArray) + 1
    ReDim Preserve MimeMapArray(i)
    MimeMapArray(i) = CreateObject("MimeMap")
    MimeMapArray(i).Extension = Ext
    MimeMapArray(i).MimeType = MType
    MimeMapObj.PutEx(ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE, "MimeMap", MimeMapArray)
    MimeMapObj.SetInfo()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the file with vim and use the ex command 'set list' it will show you any invisible characters that may be causing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-800a0408-errors.html

> If you cut and paste code from other
>   sources (e.g. web sites, other
>   editors, etc) you often bring along
>   characters that don't show up in
>   Notepad but are, nonetheless, present
>   -- or do appear as non-prinatable characters, that look like little
>   squares. If you're looking at the line
>   in question and it isn't simply an
>   unclosed string or a premature
>   carriage return, try deleting the
>   line(s) altogether and re-typing them
>   by hand. This should eliminate the
>   possibility of 'invisible' problem
>   characters mucking up the stream.

Comment: Thanks, yes I read that before.  However, I have viewed this file in Notepad and retyped the first line, but I still have same error.  Any other ideas?  Syntax is correct, no?  And isn't it saying error is with first "Dim"?

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding when you save the file, must be ANSI in NotePad